# How do you say multiples of some number?

Tags: grammar, numbers

On a specification about a data. The valid value must be multiples of 10 (10, 20, 30, ...)

How do you state that in Japanese. I saw on a document that it is written as

> Xは10,20,30・・のように10飛で付番する

Is there other way to state this in Japanese?

Comment: Note that "multiple of 10" and "10飛び" are not the same. For example, the sequence "2, 12, 22, 32, 42, ..." is not "multiples of 10" but is "10飛び".

Comment: @sawa. Arithmetic progression! What about geometric progression as in 2^1, 2^2, ...2^n ? What's that called?

Comment: @Flaw I don't know of a conventional way of saying it. I can only describe it as 等比数列.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you can try using `～の倍数で～`